# Interpretation of $T$ statistics and Adjusted $R^2$

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients, model

I'm analyzing the paper "King of the Mountain: The Shiller P/E and Macroeconomic Conditions" for my master's thesis. I would like advice on interpreting the results. The authors perform 2 regressions: 1) future stock market returns (for different time horizons, from $t$ to $k$, with $k=1,6,12,36,60,120$ months) are regressed against the CAPE (or Shiller P/E)= Exhibit 7; 2) the same response variables are regressed against a CAPE conditioned on the current values of the interest rate and inflation rate= Exhibit 8. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1kDi.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/y86GL.png) The CAPE is a good predictor of returns over long forecasting horizons (i.e., 5/10 years), while the authors demonstrate that the conditioned CAPE has better predictive power than the normal CAPE for short horizons (1,6,12 months). Observing the reported results, the authors state that the coefficients are statistically significant (the $T$ statistics must be greater than what value to claim that the coefficients are statistically significant? given that p-values are not provided). The adjusted $R^2$ values double for short-term forecasts when using the conditioned CAPE, but it is at most 0.6%. Consequently, is it correct to say that the conditioned CAPE can be used as a good predictor of short-term returns, as authors claim, considering these results? I know the $T$ statistic can be considered to understand if estimated coefficients are statistically significant but since the p-values are not provided, I wonder how can I understand if they really are (particularly for short-term forecasts in Exhibit 8). Moreover, adjusted $R^2$ double but they are still very low.